# Google cloud run: Can a service know its own url?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm wondering if a container deployed on cloud run can somehow obtain its own service url or is it impossible?

I'm wanting to know this because I want a cloud run worker that creates google cloud tasks for itself.

If it is possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 5):

Use [namespaces.services.get](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) to retrieve the cloud run service info, some information required for this api

1. Service name

   Cloud Run has provided [default environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#env-vars) `K_SERVICE`
2. Project ID
3. Region
4. Access token

Project ID, region and access token can retrieve from [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#metadata-server)

```sh
PROJECT_ID=$(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
REGION=$(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/region" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" | sed "s/.*\///")
TOKEN=$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" | jq -r '.access_token')
```

Then you can use [namespaces.services.get](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) to retrieve the cloud run service info in json, extract url with `jq`, `export` environment variable for application use

```sh
export PUCLIC_URL=$(curl -s "https://${REGION}-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/${PROJECT_ID}/services/${K_SERVICE}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" | jq -r '.status.url')
```

`curl` and `jq` may required to install, for alpine: `apk add --no-cache curl jq`

Cloud Run service account requires `run.services.get` permission to call `namespaces.services.get`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [an article to self call Cloud Run service to prevent Cold Start](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894). The code that I wrote in Go is in [my github](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/cloudrun-sigterm-selfcall)

The idea is to call the metadata server to find the project number and the region (like this you don't have this hardcoded or in env var), and then you call the namespace API.

If you need help to write it in another language, let me know.

Comment: I did this and got `undefined` for `service.status.url` (in nodejs)

Comment: Can you share you code in your question? I will try on my side and reproduce your error, and may be fix it!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the service name, you can make a GET HTTP request to `https://{endpoint}/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/{name}`

[Method: namespaces.services.get](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get)

For example :

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"  https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/your-project/services/your-service| grep url

"url": "https://cloud-run-xxxxxxxxxx-uc.a.run.app"
```