# Cloud Run get public URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Inside my code, how can I get the public URL of my Cloud Run project?

Let's suppose that my Cloud Run is hosted at:

```
https://my-cloud-run-a7jtmot2uw-uc.a.run.app
```

And I want to get this information in my code.

For example. I am using App Engine and I do the same thing in Python with the following code:

```py
public_url = "https://%s.uc.r.appspot.com" % os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"]
```

Comment: I just answered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65628822/google-cloud-run-can-a-service-know-its-own-url/65634104#65634104 Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code you can make an API call to [Method: namespaces.services.get](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) and parse status.url of the returning Service object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm worried that you can't do that this way. But you can create env variable with this url and get in in the code

`PUBLIC_URL=https://my-cloud-run-a7jtmot2uw-uc.a.run.app`

and in code

`public_url = "os.environ["PUBLIC_URL"]`

edit:
There is similar question and you can check if hiting endpoint will return you URL in managed cloud run
[Google cloud run: Can a service know its own url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65628822/google-cloud-run-can-a-service-know-its-own-url)

Comment: I was thiking on a dynamic way, like I was doing with App Engine.